# Displaying php mysqli query result with one to many relationship

Tags: php, arrays, one-to-many

Current:

| Process | Skill |
| --- | --- |
| Process A | Skill_1 |
| Process A | Skill_2 |
| Process A | Skill_3 |
| Process B | Skill_1 |
| Process B | Skill_2 |

Expected Result:

| Process | Skill |
| --- | --- |
| Process A | Skill_1, Skill_2, Skill_3 |
| Process B | Skill_1, Skill_2 |

Sample SQL:

```
SELECT p.pid,
 p.process,
 p.product_id,
 p.sr_id,
 sr.pid,
 sr.process_id,
 sr.skill_req,
 sr.availability
 FROM p
 JOIN sr
 ON  p.pid= sr.pid
 WHERE p.product_id= '20'
```

Need help how to rearrange my one to many relationship table. Tried using array
"$array= array($row['skill_req']) " but does not recognize the skill_req variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for `GROUP BY` and `GROUP_CONCAT`

For your request, start with something like this and see where you can go from there:

```
SELECT p.pid,
 p.process,
 GROUP_CONCAT(sr.skill_req),
 FROM p
 JOIN sr
 ON  p.pid= sr.pid
 WHERE p.product_id= '20'
 GROUP BY p.process
```

Note that SQL will always give you a 2-dimensional array, never more, never less. This means that the cells that you visualize as a result of a query cannot contain an array. At best, you're going to have comma-separated values, which you can turn into an array on the PHP side.

Comment: You should add `p.process` to the `GROUP BY` clause too, as you're not using an aggregate function on that in the `SELECT` clause.

Comment: Right, my mistake!

Comment: It display as my expected result. Thank you for your help